# How to send specific email to the lead when created from web-to-lead or Through API

Tags: email, web2lead

I'm creating leads from web-to-lead and through API in Salesforce and want to send specific email based on the lead data. For this I have written a trigger to send email after inserted in Salesforce. 
But the trigger does not sent the email from APEX. Why is it so?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the trigger? Did you see any errors in the console? Anyways, I bet you could accomplish this using a Process builder and an Email alert.

Comment: Are you getting the Lead source from web-to-lead from API. Depending upon values write workflows. Trigger not sending email might be as its a sandbox and deliverability is set to "No Email"?

Answer (score 0):

If its a sandbox, check the value set for Email Deliverability. It might be set to "No Email" or "System Only"